# Calculating Conditional Probability of stock prices

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a data set of stock prices, with a set of events and their probabilities as follows:

A = Change in price between current day and previous day
$$
P(A>0) = 0.548
$$
B = Correlation between today and a given day
$$
P(B \geq 0.5) = 0.030
$$
C = Price change in the last hour of the trading day
$$
P(C \geq 0.3) = 0.086
$$
The above events are not mutually exclusive, as the occurrence of one does not prevent the occurrence of another.

Furthermore, from the data set I have calculated:
$$
P(A| B) = 0.5\\
P(A | C) = 0.533
$$

If I am correct, the fact that the probability of A changes based on the occurrence of either B or C, these events are not independent?

If this is the case, assuming I had only $P(A), P(B)$ and $P(C)$, what formula should I use to calculate:
$$
P(A| B) \text{ and } P(A| C).
$$

Comment: You cannot compute those conditional probabilities from just $P(A),P(B),P(C).$ Also your notation is confusing: Is $A$ a random variable as in $P(A>0)$ or a set as in $P(A)$?

Comment: A is a random variable